# Can I see which question gave someone else the "Hero of Time" hat?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash, winter-bash-2017

Is there any way to know which question the user asked so he/her got the **Hero Of Time** hat?

[image: Hero of Time Hat]

Comment: Congrats on your new hat ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: click on the hat to find on which site the user earned it.

Step 2: go to the user's profile on that site, **Activity** tab, questions, **newest** tab, scan upward from the time when Winter Bash started, and find the first that has upvotes and was asked at 00 minutes of any hour.

However, the date when the question was asked is may not be visible easily on one page. For one thing the date might be displayed something like *"x days ago"*, so that you have to hover the mouse over it to see the details.
And even then, I saw at least one [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/246819/dessert?tab=questions) where the hover shows the last activity date instead of the creation date. So to be sure, you have to open the question to find out the creation date.

A "simpler" alternative is to use the Stack Exchange API to print the exact accurate creation dates and post links.

Sub-step 1: find the user's user ID on the site

Sub-step 2: find the site ID, using the `[edit]` link just under the **Try It** box on the [documentation page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users)

Sub-step 3: find a PC where you have `curl`, `perl` and `jq`

And run this command:

```
user=...
site=...
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/$user/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=$site" \
  | gzip -cd \
  | jq -r '.items[] | [ (.creation_date | tostring), .link ] | join(" ")' \
  | perl -lape '$_ = join(" ", scalar localtime($F[0]), $F[1])'
```

For example for `user=246819` and `site=unix` this will give (as of now):

```
Fri Dec 15 12:00:08 2017 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411022/does-at-run-a-command-later-if-the-computer-is-off-at-the-specified-time
Sat Nov  4 09:52:51 2017 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/402463/how-to-retrieve-price-information-from-www-meinfluessiggas-de-in-a-bash-script
Mon Sep 11 21:58:43 2017 https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/391679/how-to-automatically-insert-a-string-after-the-prompt
...
```

Guess which question earned the hat ;-)

Comment: thank you @janos this is a possible way, I hope there are others, if not, i will accept your answer :)

Comment: It should actually be the last one (usually), since you earn the hat the first time you post a question at 7PM in any timezone. Except that questions that are closed or not upvoted don't count, so if the oldest one is dowvoted or closed you need to look for the next one.

Comment: @DonaldDuck yeah I meant first by chronology, not as it appears in the list. But that's not accurate, as you noted as well, since it will be the first that gets an upvote (and probably not getting closed)

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, there's no way to tell this that's automatic at all, like how badges link to the post that earned the user said badge.

That said, it's not *too* difficult to figure it out yourself since you get a lot of hints.

Firstly, you can click on the user's hat list to see where they received the hat, which tells you which site to start with.

[image: How to see where the hat was earned]

Then you can go to their questions list on that site and sort by most recent - most people don't ask that many questions, so it should be pretty easy to find just by clicking on the questions to see what time they were asked.